# How would I unhide a button if user performs segue in swift?

Tags: swift, parse-platform, segue, cell, hidden

I have a button inside a cell (PFQueryTableViewController) that is hidden and I want to unhide it when the user performs a certain segue that I call programatically.

When the user taps the cell it segues to a view controller which displays the contents of the cell full screen... I want the button to unhide in this cell when the segue is called so when the user goes back to the table of cells they can see it on the cell they just tapped.

How can I do this?

Edit after questions:

inside cellRowForIndexPath I have the following for the button

```
cell.myButton.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.myButton.addTarget(self, action: "pressed:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    cell.myButton.hidden = true
```

And the segue itself carries information from the cell (stored in Parse backend) across to FullPostViewController from AllPostsTableViewController. The code for that is this (would I call the unhide in here somewhere?):

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showFullPost", sender: self)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showFullPost" {
        let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
        let fullPostVC = segue.destinationViewController as! FullPostViewController
        let object = self.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath)
        fullPostVC.post = object?.objectForKey("postContent") as? String
        let likeCount = object!.objectForKey("likedBy")!.count
        fullPostVC.likesCounted = String(likeCount)

        self.tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!, animated: true)

    }
}
```

Comment: how are you hiding this button?

Comment: Can you list any steps that you currently have taken?

Comment: I've edited with more detail! Thanks for responding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Answer thoroughly edited after thorough edit of question)

One possible solution follows below.

---

Since you mention table cells (each containing a button; I'll assume `UIButton`), I assume you populate your table view cells with `UITableViewCell` objects; some fancy subclass to the latter. In this class:

- If you haven't already, create an `@IBOutlet` from your button as a property in this class.
- Overload the method `setSelected(...)` to un-hide your button in case the `UITableViewCell` is selected (which will precede the segue)

Hence, in your `UITableViewCell` subclass, you should be able to do something along the lines:

```
// ...TableViewCell.swift

Import UIKit

// ...

class ...TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    // Properties
    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
        // button contained in UITableViewCell

    // ...

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // If table cell is selected (after which segue will follow),
        // un-hide button.
        if (selected) {
            button.hidden = false
        }
    }
}
```

Hopefully this will achieve your goal.

Comment: Note: this is an answer to the much less thorough rev 0 of the question. The edited question is now much more detailed, and I will edit this answer tomorrow into a more suitable answer (given updated question), unless someone else can answer before that. Before that, however, I have to go to bed.

Comment: Hey, just wondering whether you have that answer now? It's driving me mad haha

Comment: @ChrisWright Sorry for the wait; hopefully this can get you somewhere!

Comment: I will give this a go tomorrow and let you know! Thank you for your time!

Comment: Great! If this answer your question, please mark the question as answered (and possibly up vote the answer if you're happy with it :) ).